# c# winforms creating pictureboxes dynamically at runtime doesn't work

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create **PictureBoxes** dynamically at runtime with `c#` winforms.
My project: I want to write a program, which has a *node-GUI* (a GUI with various types of nodes, some kind of boxes, which are connected together and process an image, an audio stream or whatever).

Therefor i want to create and delete **Pictureboxes** dynamically at runtime, but my testing won't work, the form is empty.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AudioNodeGUI
{
    public partial class AudioNodeWindow : Form
    {
        public AudioNodeWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AudioNodeWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AudioNodeWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        PictureBox start_picture = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = "pictureBox",
                Size = new Size(19, 32),
                Location = new Point(100, 100),
                Visible = true,
                Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Benjamin.MBENJAMIN\Pictures\Start.png"),
            };
            start_picture.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help !

Comment: think you need to add it to the forms controls.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should put that code in the form's `Paint`Event...

Comment: Did those answers help @Ben ?

Comment: Yes, id did, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the control you created to the Forms control.

Before you Show() the picturebox, try adding this line:

```
Controls.Add(start_picture);
```

Secondly, you don't want to doing this onPaint()!

I would say you need to move it to Load() method instead, that way it will be done when the form loads, rather than everytime it's repainted!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
start_picture.Show();
```

to:

```
this.Controls.Add(start_picture);
start_picture.Show();
```

[Controls.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) tells the form that the `PictureBox` is meant to be part of **this specific form**.

*Also, you will not want to do this in in your `Paint` event handler. Leaving it there will result in many more picture boxes than you would like I expect...*

Answer (score 0):

I have change your code as :

```
 PictureBox start_picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(19, 32),
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Visible = true,
            Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"D:\test\learn.png"),
        };
        //start_picture.Show();
        Controls.Add(start_picture);
```